# Toggle color of Bootstrap open modal button onClick and on closing of modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Besides using jQuery, is there a way to change the color of the `.add-button` below so that it toggles when click and will change back when the modal is closed?

```
<div className="container">

  <button type="button" className="btn btn-md add-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span className="plus-sign">+</span> &nbsp; Contacts Keeper &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </button>

  <div className="modal fade" id="myModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the button color on click you should change it on hover. Since only in that case you will be able to see visible effect otherwise when clicked modal will be closed.

One way to use psuedo classes in css and another way to use js to change the css styles.
Also I noticed that you are using `classNames`, It means may be using react.
In that case append a predefined css class to your existing button css classes on mouse over and remove them on mouse out.

```js
function changeColor(x) {
    x.style.background = "red";
}

function normalColor(x) {
      x.style.background = "white";
  }
```

```css
#test-button:hover{
  color:red;
  background:green;
  }

#test-button:active{
  background:yellow;
  }

#close-button:hover{
  background:cyan;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="test-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal1
</button>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="test-button1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
  Launch demo modal2
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="close-button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="close-button1" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onmouseover="changeColor(this)" onmouseout="normalColor(this)">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```